# Using client credentials middleware for all API requests

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, authorization, laravel-passport

In my `routes/api.php` file, I have a route group like this:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => config('api.route_prefix'),
    'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api'],
], function() {
// ...
```

This correctly only allows users with tokens retrieved via password grant access to those routes. When trying to implement client credentials grant, I found that a [separate middleware is necessary](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens). Since the `auth:api` middleware raises an exception, this presents a conflict because I want requests with valid tokens of either grant type to access these routes.

What I found is that using just the client credential middleware seems to validate both, but I am unsure if there are any bad implications of doing so.

Is there anything wrong with circumventing the `auth:api` middleware and replacing it with `Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One apparent big downside is that the client credentials doesn't seem to have any user information in the JWT token. This causes the user resolver for the request to return null for calls to `request()->user()`. From `Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard::authenticateViaBearerToken`, this was returning `null`:

```
// If the access token is valid we will retrieve the user according to the user ID
// associated with the token. We will use the provider implementation which may
// be used to retrieve users from Eloquent. Next, we'll be ready to continue.
$user = $this->provider->retrieveById(
    $psr->getAttribute('oauth_user_id')
);
```

Tracing `$psr->getAttribute` led me to `League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator::validateAuthorization`:

```
 // Return the request with additional attributes
return $request
    ->withAttribute('oauth_access_token_id', $token->getClaim('jti'))
    ->withAttribute('oauth_client_id', $token->getClaim('aud'))
    ->withAttribute('oauth_user_id', $token->getClaim('sub'))
    ->withAttribute('oauth_scopes', $token->getClaim('scopes'));
```

All of the attributes *except* `oauth_user_id` were being set correctly via the claims on the token, `$token` in my case is an instance of `Lcobucci\JWT\Token`. So only using the client credentials middleware is not a good solution to having a single set of routes, even if using an oauth client with a specified `user_id`.

Comment: FWIW I was able to get around this by subclassing `League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AbstractGrant` and Passports service provider to register _my_ `ClientCredentialsGrant` instead of League's, [here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffsrepoaccount/11579df0efa890af5ae9ebcc8c727bdd), though this does limit me as far as any updates to the original code.